# People of Jannah are "thirty or thirty-three years", but I wasn't a Muslim at that age. Does this have any relevance?

Tags: jannah

Ahadith claim that people of Jannah are thirty-three years old:

> The people of Paradise shall enter Paradise without body hair, Murd, with Kuhl on their eyes, thirty years of age or thirty-three years.  ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/urn/678510); see also [IslamWeb.net](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=243124) and [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/20469))

However, I wasn't a Muslim when I was thirty-three years old (or, I hadn't reverted before age thirty-three).

**Question**:  Does not being a Muslim at age thirty-three have any relevance to how one exists in Jannah?

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this the right way.  I'm envisioning a snapshot of a thirty-three year old me being in Jannah.  But perhaps this is not the right mental picture.

Comment: That's good news if i might be accepted there at least i would still have all my hair ;)

Answer (score 3):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him his family and companions

No, It has not such relevance.It actually indicates glad tidings that Allah swt would make people young in jannah so that they could enjoy the blessings in jannah.Once Our Rasulullah peace be upon him showed his sense of humour where he  mentioned to an old woman that old woman cannot enter jannah see here

> Hasan Basri radiyallahu anhu says that an old woman came to
>   Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam and made a request, “O’
>   Messenger of Allah make Dua that Allah grants me entrance into
>   Jannah.”   Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam replied, “O’ Mother,
>   an old woman cannot enter Jannah.” That woman started crying and began
>   to leave. Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam said, “Say to the
>   woman that one will not enter in a state of old age, but Allah will
>   make all the women of Jannah young virgins. Allah Ta’aala says, “Lo!
>   We have created them a (new) creation and made them virgins, lovers,
>   equal in age.” (Surah Waaqi’ah, 35-37).(Shamail Tirmidhi)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Was that sense of humour or was he SAW seriou$?

Comment: @Abcd "O Mother an Old woman cannot enter Jannah" That was the sense of humour and then he clarified because companions asked to him once that do you joke so he replied that "I always say the truth when I am joking".JazakAllah